# I compiled Memtest86+ v5.01, but it can't run

Tags: c, memory, compilation

Because I need to add memtest86+ v5.01 into grub in my serial console machine, I compiled [the source code](http://memtest.org/download/5.01/memtest86+-5.01.tar.gz) with setting SERIAL_CONSOLE_DEFAULT zero to one in the config.h.

After that, I use the pre-compiled bin file to boot my Virtualbox first. It shut down when the test begins. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMlwb.jpg).

I also tried not to change the any setting, just build the source code. It still has the same problem.

Memtest86+ v4.2 does't have this problem, but it doesn't support my serial console machine's chipset. I need the ECC polling feature.

Comment: I can't read Chinese, but what do the virtualbox logs say? The error message seems to be referencing them.

Comment: @Fang It says virtual machine has some critical problem and the vm stops